# Mysql query wont work because of special characters

Tags: mysql, special-characters

I want to make simple query on my database, but it seems to be problem with latvian symbols in where clause like "ģ,č,ī,ā"

This is my query:

```
$sql="insert into c3_zrkac.tests 
select * 
FROM `web_notikumi_laiki`,`web_notikumi` 
WHERE not_id=id_not and not_vieta='Zemgales reģiona Kompetenču attīstības centrā');
mysqli_query($con1,$sql)
or die(mysqli_error($con1));
```

query  works perfect if I put it in phpmyadmin sql box.

I also tried this :

```
$sql_utf8_latvian_ci = iconv("UTF-8","ISO-8859-1",$sql);
mysqli_query($con1,$sql_utf8_latvian_ci)
or die(mysqli_error($con1));
```

but it diddnt make any difference, I dont get any errors too.

I think that its because of those symbols, maybe I have missed something?

My php script encoding UTF-8

Comment: Have you tried setting the character set in the connection string - see here how to do it - https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/specifying-character-set/

Comment: @PaulF Thanks!! I had to do It differently but you were right, i had to change character set.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Another case of adding a comment where I should have added an answer :-(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the character set to utf-8

```
/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!mysqli_set_charset($con1,"utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    exit();
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($con1));
}
```